# How to modify path alias in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, path-aliases

Currently I'm on `example.com/node/add page`. Now I wish to add content in content type = article. What I want is, when accessing path `/node/add/article`, add content url should look like `node/add/article?keyword='hello'`

And this page still opens add node article page.

I tried changing alias at /admin/config/search/path/add

`/node/add/article`

to

`node/add/article?keyword='hello'`
But it didn't worked?

Comment: Requirement seems confusing but I guess adding a simple redirection programmatically or using a module is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a custom route. You might need to use a different name than /node/add/

So in a custom module add in your_module.routing.yml

```
article_add:
  path: /add/article/{{ keyword }}
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\your_module\Form\AddArticle::AddArticleWithYourKeyword'
  requirements:
   _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

And then create a Form in your_module/src/Form/AddArticle.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class AddArticle extends ControllerBase {
    public static function AddArticleWithYourKeyword($keyword) {
         //Here you can generate your form with your added keyword and return it as a render array
    }
}
```

This will allow you to grab a form and make edits to it, or generate an entirely custom one. In my example I made it so you pass the keyboard in the path itself not as a GET variable, but if you need you can just make the route /add/article/ and then check for GET variables inside your function.

**UPDATE**
Another method would be to implement the hook_form_alter function

```
function yourmodule_or_theme_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$request = \Drupal::request();
$keyword       = $request->get('keyword');
  if (in_array($form['#form_id'], ['node_article_edit_form'])) {
    $form['keyword'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'keyword',
      '#default_value' => $keyword,
    ];
  }
}
```

Not 100% sure of the syntax but that's the general idea.

Comment: It's a very lengthy way. I think there must be an easy hack to just alter path alias patters.

Comment: Do you want to be able to do something with the keyword? You can also do a preprocess form hook and intercept the GET variable and add that value to the form before rendering it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I have nothing to do with form, node/add/article form will remain unaffected, only I have to change its alias pattern, something like node/add/article?keyword=xyz.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want node/add/article?keyword=xyz to go to the same page as node/add/article? Because that will already occur. Or do you need it so you have to put in the keyword to visit the form? Or do you want to change what page node/add/article?keyword=xyz leads to, and make it so node/add/article?keyword=xyz goes to a different page than node/add/article?

Comment: yes I want node/add/article?keyword=xyz to go to the same page as node/add/article

Comment: Is that not already happening? node/add/article?keyword=xyz should be going to node/add/article already. If that's not the case what is node/add/article?keyword=xyz bringing you instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65260/discussion-between-sugandh-khanna-and-matt).

Comment: That isn't changing the alias pattern, that is just a query string. If the query string does not affect the node form in any way, what is the point of adding code? These are not aliases either - they are system routes.

Comment: @Kevin I was confused as well. It turns out what he needed was the link on the actual admin Add Content page to link to /node/add/article?keyword=xyz instead of it linking to /node/add/article